# Find Sum of An Entry in dataframe from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a DF somewhat like this

```
Name    Likes

a        100
b        200
c        50  
a        200
d        150
a        250
a        180 
c        110
```

I want to find how many likes does each name has in total
For example in this case

a has a total of 100+200+250+180 = 730 likes

How do we implement this using pandas ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its done by `groupby()` -

```
df.groupby('Name')['Likes'].sum() #returns series

# df.groupby('Name')['Likes'].sum().reset_index() ## returns dataframe
```

You can read more about how to use group by (and its advance usage) [here](https://www.kaggle.com/akshaysehgal/how-to-group-by-aggregate-using-py).